# AWS lambda JAVA execution is not fetching SPRING_PROFILE_ACTIVE from Lambda Environment Variable

Tags: spring-boot, aws-lambda

Currently I have set AWS Lambda Environment variable "SPRING_PROFILE_ACTIVE=qa" but the profile is not getting selected in Spring Boot java Application.

Has any tried using spring profile active as environment variable in AWS Lambda

Answer (score 0):

It should be profiles with an "s":

```
spring_profiles_active
```

It's plural because it takes a comma separated list.